# Allure.createStep is not a function

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, allure

I wanted to add the Test Step to Allure Reporting and in Allure API its given that create step can be used.

I am using the function as

```
import {allureReporter} from "./../node_modules/jasmine-allure-reporter/src/Jasmine2AllureReporter.js";

allure.createStep('Outer step', function() {})
```

But it's throwed error that createStep is not function.

However, when i see the 'Jasmine2AllureReporter.js' file there is no function allure.createStep.

So can you please help me how to usee the allure API in my Protractor Test with jasmine2 framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use Allure report incorrectly. Look at [the Readme of Allure-jasmine package](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine#using-allure-reporter-in-protractor)

You need to add the following content into your `protractor.conf.js` file:

```
exports.config = {
  // I assume that you already have this line
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  onPrepare: function() {
    var AllureReporter = require('jasmine-allure-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new AllureReporter({
      resultsDir: 'allure-results'
    }));
  }
}
```

Allure-reporter should be installed at `onPrepare` stage. Global `allure` object will be injected into your test code automatically with proper context. No need to import anything extra.

Also, if you later see problems with Typescript, look at [this issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine/issues/21) for a solution.

Comment: Hi Boris,
This is already been added to conf file and report is getting generated. However, i want to add Test step to report and for that allure.CreateStep() is used. But when i used , it shows that Allure.Create Step is not a function.

Comment: Then look at the issue: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine/issues/21
I believe that this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, i looked into it and it works.
Also can you tell me how to know which test step failed. I have 20 test steps and out of which 2 steps are failed.
I can see the failure reason for the test but is there any way where i can add and see which step failed out of 20.
I have added assertions inside the Test Step only

allure.description("Failing test cases puporsely")
         var stepFn = allure.createStep('[{0}] Saving the settings',function(){
          expect('2').toBe('3',"3 is not matching 2")
     });

Comment: Unfortunately, this is Jasmine limitation by design. The fact, that Jasmine allows you to make multiple errors out of a single test case, doesn't let you to determine, which step had caused that.

As a kind of solution I can only suggest to use Mocha, that has different architecture without this limitations.

Comment: Thanks! for clarification Boris. Really appreciated.

So even if you chai as a package it won't work?